# Is it a good practice to mitigate CLR Exceptions in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, clr

I recently developed an application which runs ASP.NET MVC, and noticed that when it starts, some CLR Exceptions are being thrown. I marked the "Common Language Runtime" checkbox under Exceptions menu, and all the exceptions now are causing a break.

I corrected some of the errors (which was related to null references envolving models which wasn't passed to views and later referenced on Razor controls), and some of them appear to be internally related to MVC, like this one

> A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
>
> Additional information: 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' does not contain a definition for 'ReturnUrl'

This happens on every creation of ViewBag properties:

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl; //error here
    return View(new LoginModel());
}
```

Since it doesn't affect my application flow and it starts and goes fine, should I be worried about this? Is this harmful to server or application's performance or any other stuff?

Comment: @JohnB I'm not sure if it's a duplicate. I deliberately enabled CLR Exceptions to check in detail what they were about. I want to know whether those exceptions in a general way are harmful to the application or I can forget about it. This is not directly related to `RuntimeBinderException`

Comment: The specific error you are getting can be considered as false positive as it is MVC feature. You need to see if you can supress such errors so that they don't pop up.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I know that i can avoid those errors popping up by disabling CLR Exceptions. But should I forget about those kind of exceptions, or they can harm performance?